# Count all distinct excptions that is present in log file(file is gz file) :Unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have 20gb log file and I want to get all distinct exceptions presnet in log file. log fie is a gz file.

Please help me to do this. I am a naive in unix.

Comment: How your log looks like ?

Comment: You have a log file that is 20GB, compressed? I would strongly recommend against blindly running any of the unexplained commands that have been presented as answers so far, as they will take _ages_ to run and probably cause your system to run out of memory. It is *vital* that you show us the structure of your log file so that we can help you effectively.

Answer (score 0):

zcat file.txt.gz | sort | uniq -c

Comment: $ zgrep -o "[a-zA-Z]*Exception"  catalina.out.save| sort -u | uniq -u

Answer (score 0):

```
gzip -cd file.gz | 
    perl -nle '
        $H{$_}+=1 for/\w+Exception/g;
        END{
            print"$_ => $H{$_}" for sort keys %H
        }
    '
```

Comment: $ zgrep -o "[a-zA-Z]*Exception"  catalina.out.save| sort -u | uniq -u. This is how I have done